# Parse the sentence 「この保証書は、記載の内容で無料修理を行うことをお約束するものです」

Tags: particle-で, formal-nouns

The above sentence is taken from a 保証書 (from a reading exercise). Having searched for the sentence, it seems to be a fairly standard sentence in warranties.

I have two question about the sentence.

1. What does で mean in 記載の内容で? Because of? According to?
2. Then sentence ends with ものです. Regarding the もの here, does it simply mean “thing”, “object” (so that the sentence means “this warranty is the thing that guarantees ...”)? Or is this a special usage of ものだ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, understand the construct 「この〜は〜ものです」. It's a pattern used to describe the power of something (usually an official document or some artifact). For example, 「パスポートは各国に国民の安全な通行を要請するもです」,「王冠は、正当な継承者であることを証明するものです」.

Then let's look at the rest. 記載の内容で無料修理を行う means "perform free repairs according to the terms described in the document". A more literal translation would be "With what is printed, perform free repairs".

So all taken together it means: This guarantee document certifies that we promise to perform free repairs according to the terms printed on it.